# Redirect from controller to external url using basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, redirect

I have a portal in ASP.NET MVC3 that in some specific operation I need to open in a new tab a external portal, developed from other team, that requires basic authentication.

I know that we have the redirect method in the controller that allows to redirect to any URL. But I don't know how to pass credentials to this.

I was trying something like this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(redirectUrl);

request.Method = "GET";
request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;

var cred = new NetworkCredential("user1", "pass123");
var cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(new Uri(redirectUrl), "Basic", cred);

request.Credentials = cache;
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

return Redirect(response.ResponseUri.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get credentials from the browser to the server.  They can go in the URL or they can go in an authorization header.  The URL method is pretty easy to implement, see [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters).  For the authorization header, Wikipedia has instructions on [how to construct it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) but I'm not sure how you can cause it to be sent for a page request (as opposed to an Ajax request where it's possible).